# Gitlab CI : Multiple project

Tags: gitlab, microservices, devops, gitlab-ci

I have two projects on gitlab : a frontend (angular) and a module backend (spring). So I would like to use a pipeline to run tests on the frontend after backend was tested and builded . For example, I'd like run tests and build backend modules when it succeeds I'd like run the frontend tests which call the api back before I deploy it as below :

[image]

**Frontend pipeline .gitlab-ci.yml** : stage back : tests => build the backend **then** stage front : run the tests on api back => build the frontend

How I can do this, please ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use Gitlabs Multi-Project Pipelines Feature: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html#multi-project-pipelines

For example you can add a build-backend job to your frontend gitlab-ci.yml. This job starts the pipeline in the Start/backend Repository and waits for it to end (configured with `strategy: depend`). In the gitlab-ci.yml of the backend project, you can build and test the backend modules and after this pipeline finishes, the next jobs in the frontend pipeline are executed.

```
build-backend:
  stage: build-backend
  trigger:
    project: Start/backend
    strategy: depend
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything, so I have to use the trigger API

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GitLab Pipelines API to [create a new pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#create-a-new-pipeline) in the frontend project.

This means you would have two `.gitlab-ci.yml` files -- one in the backend project, and one in the frontend project.

See also:  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html  (you'll need an access token to auth with the GitLab API.  You can so via Oauth2 or by using a personal access token, which you might find easier to start with).

Comment: Thanks, I looked through the docs but I think it’s not possible to run end-to-end testing. I could to ensure all the module dependencies are ok before running unit tests and building the project but if I want to build a project B and use it like api rest on the project A to run e2e tests it’s not possible. My goal is the gitlab-ci run e2e front tests before the deployment as below :

Run front tests (project A) -> call api rest on the backend ( project B builded by gitlab-ci ) -> backend -> call DB services

Comment: Okay.  Great answer from @danielnelz below, then.

Comment: @jonn Have you managed to find a solution for that problem?